CMake project with internal library dependency
I am using the cmake init template to build a basic cmake configuration for building a shared and static library. In addition to my main library, I would like to build some external source files as (external library), i.e. my project structure looks as follows
myLib
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
  |-- source
    |-- *.cxx
  |-- include
    |-- *.h 
  |-- thirdparty
    |-- myDependency
      |-- CMakeLists.txt
      |-- *.h 
      |-- *.cxx 

For that purpose I have the following top-level CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

include(cmake/prelude.cmake)

project(
    myLib
    VERSION 0.1.0
    DESCRIPTION "Project description"
    HOMEPAGE_URL "https://example.com/"
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

include(cmake/project-is-top-level.cmake)
include(cmake/variables.cmake)

# Add the thirdparty directory to the CMake module path
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/myDependency)

# ---- Declare library ----

# Globbing all .cxx files in the myLib directory
file(GLOB myLib_SOURCES "source/*.cxx")

add_library(
    myLib_myLib
    ${myLib_SOURCES}
)
add_library(myLib::myLib ALIAS myLib_myLib)

# Link against external libraries
target_link_libraries(myLib_myLib PUBLIC myDependency)

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  target_include_directories(myLib_myLib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myLib)
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(
    myLib_myLib
    BASE_NAME myLib
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME export/myLib/myLib_export.h
    CUSTOM_CONTENT_FROM_VARIABLE pragma_suppress_c4251
)

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  target_compile_definitions(myLib_myLib PUBLIC myLib_STATIC_DEFINE)
endif()

set_target_properties(
    myLib_myLib PROPERTIES
    CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden
    VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN YES
    VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
    SOVERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}"
    EXPORT_NAME myLib
    OUTPUT_NAME myLib
)

target_include_directories(
    myLib_myLib ${warning_guard}
    PUBLIC
    "\$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
)

target_include_directories(
    myLib_myLib SYSTEM
    PUBLIC
    "\$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/export>"
)

target_compile_features(myLib_myLib PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

# ---- Install rules ----

if(NOT CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES)
  include(cmake/install-rules.cmake)
endif()

# ---- Examples ----

if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  option(BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build examples tree." "${myLib_DEVELOPER_MODE}")
  if(BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(example)
  endif()
endif()

# ---- Developer mode ----

if(NOT myLib_DEVELOPER_MODE)
  return()
elseif(NOT PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  message(
      AUTHOR_WARNING
      "Developer mode is intended for developers of myLib"
  )
endif()

include(cmake/dev-mode.cmake)

This seems to compile, but I get the following error from the CMake configuration:
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "myLibTargets" ...) includes target "myLib_myLib" which requires target "myDependency" that is not in any export set.

I figured this comes from the include of cmake/install-rules.cmake include, which looks as follows:
if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  set(
      CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR "include/myLib-${PROJECT_VERSION}"
      CACHE STRING ""
  )
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR PROPERTY TYPE PATH)
endif()

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# find_package(<package>) call for consumers to find this project
set(package myLib)

install(
    DIRECTORY
    include/
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/export/"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
    COMPONENT myLib_Development
)

install(
    TARGETS myLib_myLib
    EXPORT myLibTargets
    RUNTIME #
    COMPONENT myLib_Runtime
    LIBRARY #
    COMPONENT myLib_Runtime
    NAMELINK_COMPONENT myLib_Development
    ARCHIVE #
    COMPONENT myLib_Development
    INCLUDES #
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${package}ConfigVersion.cmake"
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

# Allow package maintainers to freely override the path for the configs
set(
    myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${package}"
    CACHE STRING "CMake package config location relative to the install prefix"
)
set_property(CACHE myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR PROPERTY TYPE PATH)
mark_as_advanced(myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR)

install(
    FILES cmake/install-config.cmake
    DESTINATION "${myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
    RENAME "${package}Config.cmake"
    COMPONENT myLib_Development
)

install(
    FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${package}ConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
    COMPONENT myLib_Development
)

install(
    EXPORT myLibTargets
    NAMESPACE myLib::
    DESTINATION "${myLib_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
    COMPONENT myLib_Development
)

if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  include(CPack)
endif()

The myDependency library is defined in the thirdparty/myDependency dir with
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# Name of the library
project(myDependency LANGUAGES CXX)

# Globbing source and header files
file(GLOB myDependency_SOURCES "*.cxx")

# Declare the library
add_library(myDependency SHARED ${myDependency_SOURCES})

# myDependency include directory
target_include_directories(myDependency PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty)

Can someone explain what is happening and what I would need to change in my configuration to fix this issue?

Unrelated, but don't use this file(GLOB myLib_SOURCES "source/*.cxx") it will not detect new sources added to the project.

Difficult to reproduce without all this cmake-init stuff, e.g. cmake directory with helper files. Does this example have to be so complex, maybe better just start with simple add_library and add_subdirectory, without any fancy properties and install rules? From the CMakeLists.txt you posted, I cannot see any dependency from myLib_myLib to myDependency. In fact, myDependency seems to be not defined anywhere, unless you define it in 3rd party directory.

@pptaszni Yes, myDependency is defined in the CMakeLists.txt in the thirdparty/myDependency directory. I added that to the thread.

But you never use myDependency anywhere. I can't reproduce this issue with simple example like add_executable(main main.cpp) and then your big install command. Anyway, don't start with 1000 lines of CMake and then try to fix it. Start easy, and then build on top of that.

Right, there was actually a typo in what I had in the top-levle CMakeLists. I am using myDependencyc to link to my main library: target_link_libraries(myLib_myLib PUBLIC myDependency)

"Can someone explain what is happening and what I would need to change in my configuration to fix this issue?" - You need either to install and export the myDependency library, or make PRIVATE dependency from it. Both these approaches are covered in the duplicate question.

@Tsyvarev instead of just closing this, maybe you could just answer the question in the context? I already tried what was described there, but was not successful. Just closing the question is not very welcoming to beginners...

"I already tried what was described there, but was not successful." - In the duplicate question there are two answers which provides different solutions. So, what exactly have you tried? Add your fair attempt (code!) into the question post. A statement "I have tried everything" is useless unless an attempt is demonstrated in the question post.
